# Magento 2 email issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email

Magento 2 store email is not working.
Order, new customer, forget password.

Please help to find the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: let me know whether you are talking about local or server? that means whether your site is in server?

Comment: Website is in AWS server. Domain is with godaddy.
Magento 2 is fresh installed with paid theme.

Comment: can you install SMTP extension for email : https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

Comment: have u contacted customer support? since some of the servers not support emails based on the package u have taken, better ask them and get back

Comment: @Prashant - yes I have installed the extension but I am unable to configure it.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa - No I have not contacted support yet. I will contact them today.

Comment: @PrashantPatel let me know what extension you have installed for emails?

Comment: @PrashantPatel - I have used the same extension which you have given.

Comment: @PrashantPatel - if I want to use any gmail personal email on magento 2 then what settings required on mageplaza smtp plugin